# Finding an unmanaged dll API?

Tags: c#, api, dll

I am writing in C#.
How can i find out which methods/functions I can use in an unmanaged dll that doesn't belong to windows?
Exmaple : I have some installed software on my computer, it has a dll, and i want to know what my options are as to creating code to connect to that software?

Answer (score 7):

For native DLL's that you do not have a reference for you can use the dumpbin utility in the Visual Studio SDK to extract the list of exported functions in a DLL.

Dumpbin reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(VS.71).aspx

And a CodeProject page giving some additional details on how to use dumpbin in conjunction with finding the correct P/Invoke signatures is here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/usingcppdll.aspx#Retrieve

Answer (score 1):

[PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) is great resource for .NET interop.  They list not only the functions available in Windows native libraries, but also the signature you need to use in your .NET code.

Comment: Does pinvoke.net include dlls not in win32?

Comment: I think there are other unmanaged APIs on there, but I'm not sure which ones.

Answer (score 1):

use Depends.exe (which comes along with VS).

Depends would display all the exported function that can be invoked from Managed code using Pinvoke.

Answer (score 0):

I read a blog about PInvoke Interop Assistant, which can deal with our own DLLs as well
http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that **if it's a COM assembly**, like a VB6 COM component, it can be browsed in the `Object Explorer` in Visual Studio and that's pretty nice because it breaks everything out for you quite nicely.